# JavaScript/JQuery Div Delay Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have created a star rating for a site and need to close the div after the user has clicked a rating. I've managed to do so but need to add a delay into the function so it takes 2/3 seconds after the user has clicked it.

I have incorporated a delay in the div showing up using jquery as shown below but need to add to the javascript function this time and I am lost where to start.

```
function testFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("video-rating");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style=display = "block";
  } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

This is the jquery in my JSP document. If there is a way to add jquery to the function that would be great but I'm unsure with this.

```
<script>
    $('#video-rating').hide(0).delay(4000).show(0);
</script>
```

**Edit** I should of been clearer, I've passsed the testFunction into an onclick within the actual star ratings, so when they're clicked it's currently running the function and closing!

Comment: None of the above codes closes the div. Do you want to show it again after a delay?

Comment: Sorry about that I should of been clearer, I've passed the testFunction into an onclick within the actual star ratings, so when they're clicked it's currently running the function and closing! @AliSheikhpour

Comment: $('#video-rating').delay(4000).hide(0);
$('#video-rating').delay(0).show(0);

Comment: @Deepak Thank you but sadly not working. Would you know how to integrate a delay in the already done JS function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `setTimout`:

```
// Define a timer as global variable so we can cancel it anywehere:
var mytimer; 

function testFunction() {
  //Clear previous click effect if exists:
  clearTimeout(mytimer);

  var x = document.getElementById("video-rating");

  //assigning the timeout to global variable we created before:
  mytimer = setTimeout(function(){
       if (x.style.display === "none") {
           x.style=display = "block";
       } else {
           x.style.display = "none";
       }
   },666); //666 miliseconds equals to 2/3 second
}
```

using Jquery delay:

```
function testFunction() {
    $("#video-rating").delay(666).hide(0); //or toggle(0) if you want to show on next click
}
```

if you want to cancel the previous click effect you may add stop() to the jquery queue:

```
function testFunction() {
    $("#video-rating").stop().delay(666).hide(0); //or toggle(0) if you want to show on next click
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: Ali, before I try to reword it as another question.. Do you know if it is possible to create it so that the 2/3 seconds is reset if the user does choose to change their answer? As currently if they press the first star and swap to the second, the timer is still going as if it is the first if this makes sense. I have tried to wrap the setTimeout function around the last else statement but this didn't work. Any possible ideas?

Comment: Yes I will complete the current answer to cover your new question. You can vote up the answer if it was helpful.@JackC98

Comment: Please check the answer again. I have added some comments and new lines.@JackC98

Comment: I voted up already! I am having an issue with the new code you have commented, it's now delaying at all now after a rating has been clicked. @AliSheikhpour

Comment: Apologies, I should of checked my spelling! Works perfectly thank you for all your help!

Comment: I'm glad that it works. You just checked the answer as accepted. You can also vote up an answer if it deserves @JackC98

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
function testFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("video-rating");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style=display = "block";
  } else {
      setTimeout(function(){
          x.style.display = "none";
      },3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: It won't let me approve two answers to work, but thank you very much this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use this Jquery function to avoid set time interval

```
$("#video-rating").hide('slow');
           (or)
$("#video-rating").hide('fade');
```